# Creating node object from var-args arguments

Tags: swift

I have the following Node class

```
class Node<T> {
    var data: T
    var next: Node<T>?

    init(_ items: Any...) {
       // self.data = items[0] as! T
    }
}
```

and my goal is to initialize the node with the constructor above like this :

`var sampleNode =  Node<Any>(Node<Int>(2, 15), 4, Node<Any>(5, Node<Int>(7, 9)))`

How can I achieve this with varargs?

Comment: `Node<Any>(Node<Int>(2, 15), 4, Node<Any>(5, Node<Int>(7, 9)))` seems to represent a tree structure, but your `Node` class seems to represent a linked list node. What are you trying to create? A linked list or a tree?

Comment: LinkedList , the order of the elements should be 2,15,4,5,7,9 and from the start as you go next you can see these values in that order until the end.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean!

Comment: I don’t think you can do this. An array of Any is usually a bad smell in Swift.

Comment: What would `data` and `next` be if I do `Node()`?

Comment: It is assumed that always value will be passed for data , but yeah we can make a init() constructor by setting default value for data = 0 and next will be "nil"

Comment: @Mark By saying `data = 0` you are assuming the type `T` here... Can data be `T?` instead?

Comment: We can't that is the definition of the class :(

Comment: I guess if we recursively fetch all the arguments we can save them in array and then initialize the node , but not sure how to implement that

Comment: What exactly can you do to the class? Can you add a new initialiser? New computed properties? It would be useful to have a `init(data:next:)` here.

Comment: yes I can add new initialiser and new computed properties but not touch the defined 2 properties and constructor signature above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key problem here is "how do I combine the items in `items` into a big list?". We can simplify the problem into a smaller one: "How do I combine 2 `Any`s, which can be either `T` or `Node<T>`, into a single list, represented by a `Node<T>`?". (This is what `combine2Anys` does below) You can easily see that there are 4 cases to this problem:

- the first item is a `Node<T>`, the second item is a `T`,
- both items are `Node<T>`
- the first time is `T`, the second item is a `Node<T>`
- both items are `T`

You just need to handle each case in turn. And then, use this method on the first two items of `items`, then on the result of that and the third item, then on the result of *that* and the fourth item, and so on.

```
class Node<T> {
    var data: T
    var next: Node<T>?

    init(_ items: Any...) {
        func combine2Anys(_ x: Any, _ y: Any) -> Node<T> {
            switch (x, y) {
            case (let node as Node<T>, let t as T):
                node.end.next = Node(data: t, next: nil)
                return node
            case (let node1 as Node<T>, let node2 as Node<T>):
                node1.end.next = node2
                return node1
            case (let t as T, let node as Node<T>):
                return Node(data: t, next: node)
            case (let t1 as T, let t2 as T):
                return Node(data: t1, next: Node(data: t2, next: nil))
            default:
                // something other than Node<T> and T are in the passed in array
                fatalError()
            }
        }

        if items.count == 0 {
            fatalError() // it's undefined what we should do when items is empty
        } else if items.count == 1 {
            data = items.first as! T
            next = nil
        } else {
            var combined = combine2Anys(items[0], items[1])
            for i in 2..<items.count {
                combined = combine2Anys(combined, items[i])
            }
            data = combined.data
            next = combined.next
        }
    }

    // find the last node of the list
    var end: Node<T> {
        var node = self
        while node.next != nil {
            node = node.next!
        }
        return node
    }

    init(data: T, next: Node<T>?) {
        self.data = data
        self.next = next
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
let list = Node<Int>(1, Node<Int>(2, 15), 4, Node<Int>(5, Node<Int>(7, 9)))
```

Note all you should be using the same generic type all the time.

But really though, this is really ugly, mainly because of the casts and stuff. You lose all compile-time type safety. I assume this is one of those "weird requirements of homework". If I were to do this in the real world, I would change the usage to:

```
let list = Node(Node(1), Node(Node(2), Node(15)), Node(4), Node(Node(5), Node(Node(7), Node(9))))
```

And I would have these two initialises instead:

```
init(_ items: Node<T>...) {
    if items.count == 1 {
        data = items.first as! T
        next = nil
    } else {
        items[0].end.next = items[1]
        for i in 2..<items.count {
            items[i - 1].end.next = items[i]
        }
        data = items[0].data
        next = items[0].next
    }
}

init(_ item: T, next: Node<T>? = nil) {
    self.data = item
    self.next = next
}
```

Comment: Hey I was playing around it and in that case :  Node<Any>(Node<Int>(2, 3), 7, Node<Any>(2, Node<Int>(9, 4))) didn't seem to work

Comment: @Mark what’s `flatten`? Also, you need to use `Int`, never `Any` for the generic argument.

Comment: flatten was another function.It seems that I have to make it to work with Any as the example above that is how I am required :(. Any idea how to do it?A possibility is to create another function in which this "downcasting" will happen and then return "self" or just somehow edit the constructor you have implemented

Comment: I think only for numbers it will be used so if this can help T somehow to resolve correctly

Comment: @Mark I think what I have done here is coincidentally what you should have done for `flatten`, as I am flattening many linked lists. Do you actually know what this initialiser should do?

Comment: Yeah indeed the constructor flattens the nodes.With the last question ,did you mean what should the constructor do in order to flatten them to a particular type and remove the Any ?

Comment: @Mark No, I mean I don't think that's how the constructor should be implemented, because apparently you have another method - `flatten` - that does this same thing. I feel like `flatten` should be implemented the way I did in my answer, not the constructor. My suspicion is that you misinterpreted what the constructor should do. Just to confirm, this is homework, right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214604/discussion-between-mark-and-sweeper).